# Add Azure Linux VM to Vault

Tags: linux, azure, backup

I am unable to add any Linux VM's to a vault for backup. I created a vault in the same region as my servers (East US) but when I do a discovery it does not find anything. I tried adding a vault to another subscription and it found only the server in that region. How do I make it see all my VM's?  Or, anyone have another solution to backup Linux (Ubuntu) VM's? I've spent hours searching.

Thanks!

Comment: use serverfault.com for IT Pro specific questions. Stackoverflow is for development only.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 regions East US, make sure you have selected the correct one. You won't find VMs in a region that's in different from the vault.

There's no Microsoft solution atm to backup Linux VMs other than Recovery Services.

There's a few third party solutions. A popular one and homologated by Microsoft is Commvault:

https://www.microsoft.com/enterprise/partner/commvault/default.aspx